# MyBatis filter building does not like IN clause

Tags: java, xml, mybatis

So I'm building my own filtering by letting a user create their own conditions. And so far everything was great until I needed to add the `IN` clause.

**Mapper.xml**

```
 <select id="selectResultCount"
        parameterType="Filter"
        resultType="long">
    SELECT COUNT(rank)
    FROM ${view}
    <where>
        <if test="conditions != null">
            <foreach collection="conditions"
                     item="condition"
                     open=""
                     separator=" AND "
                     close="">
                <if test="condition.operator.value.toString() == 'IN'">
                    ${condition.lhs} in
                    <foreach collection="condition.getRhsCondition()" item="rhs" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                        '${rhs}'
                    </foreach>
                </if>
                ${condition.lhs} ${condition.operator.value} #{condition.rhs}
            </foreach>
        </if>
    </where>

</select>
```

So the user can build a list of conditions and then I tear them down to rebuild them. Pretty simple, for instance they can create something like `myColumn = myParam` and the filter will create the sql query `Select * From myTable where myColumn = myParam`

However, when a user uses `IN`, it all goes downhill:

```
 org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'MY_COLUMN'.
### The error may exist in mybatis-mapper.xml
### The error may involve mapper.selectResultCount-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT COUNT(rank)         FROM MY_TABLE          WHERE MY_COLUMN in                         (                             'PARAM1'                         ,                             'PARAM2'                         )                                          MY_COLUMN IN ?
### Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'MY_COLUMN '.
```

Of course this example just gets the number of results back, but the problem still persists. Why does Mybatis not like `IN` and is there a way I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is put twice in the query.

Once correctly by the code inside the if and a second time by the code after the if statement.

Your query ends with "MY_COLUMN IN ?":

```
SELECT COUNT(rank) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN in ('PARAM1','PARAM2') MY_COLUMN IN ?
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me. I created separate if statements for each query and got it to successfully work.